SQL query returning an unwanted first row
When I ran an SQL query in BigQuery to get some summary data from a public dataset, the first row returned is not something I want in the results.
Query used:
SELECT 
    usertype,
    CONCAT (start_station_name, ' to ', end_station_name) AS route,
    COUNT (*) as num_trips,
    ROUND(AVG(CAST(tripduration AS INT64)/60), 2) AS duration 
FROM 
    bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips
GROUP BY
    start_station_name,
    end_station_name,
    usertype
ORDER BY
    num_trips DESC
LIMIT 10

Results:
Query results

I think your query is returning the correct response.  The puzzle is that the data you are querying may contain rows (records) that you are not expecting.  For example, there appears to be values for usertype that are:

blank
Subscriber
Customer

there also seems to be MANY rows where start_station_name is blank and/or end_station_name is blank.  As such, these values are being included in your query result.  This opens up the story of "data cleanliness" ... it may be that the data Google gives is "raw data" and you may want to clean the data before use.  For example, you may want to exclude rows where usertype, start_station_name or end_station_name is blank.  You can filter these out either with a WHERE clause or by using a Common Table Expression (CTE).
